# Приложение забанили

Tags: android, google-play

Здравствуйте. Я написал приложение для прослушивания музыки ВК. Приложение использует фейковый токен, чтобы юзер мог слушать не входя в свой акк. Как бы вход есть, но юзер об этом не знает. Также используется id приложения kate mobile. Также есть закачка музыки. Приложение и аккаунт забанили! Купил новый, убрал возможность закачки, выложил и опять забанили приложение и аккаунт? Это что такое?

Comment: А что сказала поддержка то? Когда банят сообщают формальную причину - а именно какой пункт *Соглашения* оно нарушает - если не сложно цитату в студию.

Comment: Без причины. Делал заказчику

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 6.3. Пользователю при использовании Сайта запрещается:

  - 6.3.1. регистрироваться в качестве Пользователя от имени или вместо другого лица («фальшивый аккаунт») или регистрировать группу (объединение) лиц или юридическое лицо в качестве Пользователя. При этом, возможна регистрация от имени и поручению другого физического лица или юридического лица при условии получения необходимых полномочий в порядке и форме, предусмотренных законодательством Российской Федерации;
  - 6.3.2. вводить Пользователей в заблуждение относительно своей личности, используя логин и пароль другого зарегистрированного Пользователя;

Выдержка из [**пользовательского соглашения**](https://vk.com/terms) сайта vk.com.

Comment: судя по тегам, у автора забанили приложение в гуглплее, а не ВКшный аккаунт

Comment: @rjhdby  по вашему они не могли забанит аккаунт за нарушение соглашения с сайтом?

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что гуглу есть какое либо дело до взаимоотношений автора и ВК

Comment: @rjhdby даже если это и так, и блокировка произошла не по этой причине, автору есть о чем задуматься при использовании фейковых аккаунтов